# Design a Turing Machine which accepts strings $x \# y$ where $x \ge y$

Tags: turing-machines

> Imagine you are designing a TM where $x$ and $y$ are binary representation( $x \ge y$). the TM should accept $1101\#1001$ and reject strings such as $110\#10001$, as well as it could reject if you have more than one $\#$ or less than one $\#$.

Now, I have tried doing this. my idea is that:

1. For step one is to mark the left side first input as X, then scan to the right until you find a # sign, go to step 2, else if # sign not there reject
2. For step 2, zigzag left most side and compare each input to compare the 1's with each other. but i think i'm way off.

Comment: `Imagine you are designing…` Done. Please balance all dues. (Does the problem statement somehow come to a conclusion not shown?)

Answer (score 1):

> zigzag left most side and compare each input to compare the 1's with each other.

That is the right idea -- comparing the input one character at a time will work.

However we should be careful that we are comparing the right digits. For example, we don't want to say that `11` is bigger than `101` just because we compared the first two digits only, and said that `11` is bigger than `10`. So, maybe it would be helpful to have, as a first step, to see which of them has more digits. Make sure that you ignore leading zeros when doing this.

> but i think i'm way off

Not at all, you have the right idea.